# Can one use the Google Maps API to nest polygons and navigate by them?

Tags: api, google

Google Maps API lets one use [polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays) to create shapes on a map.

What I wish to do is nest these polygons, and use them to describe data which can then be used for navigation.

Let's say that the data is population density. A series of nested polygons would surround a major city, each one with a value. The most densely populated city centers would have a small polygon with a value 10 (for very dense) and the suburbs might be surrounded by a larger polygon of value 5 (moderate density) and the countryside might be inside a giant polygon of value 1 (low density).

I would want to let a user navigate by these polygon values. For example, someone looking for the closest inner city area might be in a area of value 3 and might want to get to the closest area of value 8.

Setting aside for the moment how I would get the population density data into polygons (That is a problem for another day), Is there any existing way to do this utilizing Google Maps API and its polygon feature? Is there a better way to approach this problem that I am not considering?

Comment: The google API doesn't route via polygons, it routes via lat,long coordinates. and you receive a google polyline as a result. so you would need to calculate the center coords of an area, would need t write your own, find the closest method, and then simply route between current coords to target.

Comment: Well I was thinking I would find the nearest point within, say, a level 8 pop density polygon/area, and then get directions to there. Would that be possible?

Comment: Also is there anyway to associate values with polygons such as I describe?

Comment: In GeoJson, you have features, and every feature can have custom properties. So yes you can store for a polygon some information. But google api can't assist you in finding the nearest point within a given polygon. That needs to be calculated on your own

Comment: OK, so I will need to do something to the effect of: 1. Find N possible destinations that are in polygons of the desired destination value, 2. Find the route to all of them, 3. Present the user to the shortest. The google API will assist me in finding each of those 3, but the hard part, finding the most efficient route, is up to me.

Comment: The difficulty here appears to be that I am not interested in the shortest route to a specific destination, but to a destination that matches a certain criteria (that it has a value of X in the polygon covering it)

Comment: Also I'm interested in reaching any point within the polygon, not the center, which further complicates things.

Answer (score 1):

If by nesting polygones you simply mean putting one shape inside another consider this:

```
// This example creates a simple polygon representing the Bermuda Triangle.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268},
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var triangleCoords = [
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
    {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
/* .-=== center ===-. */
    {lat: 25.321, lng: -66.118},
/* .-=== inner box ===-. */
    {lat: 25.321, lng: -69.757},
    {lat: 24.321, lng: -69.757},
    {lat: 24.321, lng: -70.757},
    {lat: 25.321, lng: -70.757},
    {lat: 25.321, lng: -69.757},
/* '-=== inner box ===-' */    
    {lat: 25.321, lng: -66.118},
/* '-=== center ===-' */
    {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}

  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
}
```

Which produces:

[image]

It could certainly look better but it shows that nesting of shapes is already possible with a polygon.

From your comment:

> That is what I mean, but I don't want one to create a "hole" in the polygon, I want to have polygons contain one another and each polygon have a value (representing some data associated with that geographical area) that can be used for directions (i. e. go to the nearest point in a polygon with value 8) - [Brian C](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/242231/brian-c)

You can just create another polygon:

```
  var boxCoords = [
    {lat: 25.321, lng: -69.757},
    {lat: 24.321, lng: -69.757},
    {lat: 24.321, lng: -70.757},
    {lat: 25.321, lng: -70.757},
    {lat: 25.321, lng: -69.757}
  ]

    // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaBox = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: boxCoords, 
    strokeColor: '#FFF000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FFF000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  bermudaBox.setMap(map);
```

Combined with the previous that gives you:

[image]

Comment: That is what I mean, but I don't want one to create a "hole" in the polygon, I want to have polygons contain one another and each polygon have a value (representing some data associated with that geographical area) that can be used for directions (i. e. go to the nearest point in a  polygon with value 8)

Comment: @BrianC note edit